# searching multiple txt files for data and reporting result to new table

Tags: r

I have thousands of txt files containing Mass, %Base data. I need to search each file for a row within a specific  mass range. Then, report that row into a new table with the filename as an additional character. The goal is a table of (Mass, %Base, Filename) for all of the text files based on the condition of the search.

Existing File example for file1name.txt:

```
Mass %Base 
100 .1 
101 26.2 
...
900 0
```

Goal:

```
Mass %Base File
375.004 98 file1name
375.003 96 file2name
```

My current code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

#setwd to where data is located
setwd("Z:/Dnigra") 

#set path where data is located
path <- "Z:/Dnigra" 

mc <- 375.3 #mc is the calculated target mass
limit<- 0.1 # the width of the search window

#finds the files with the correct extensions
fs <-list.files(path, pattern=glob2rx("*.txt$")) 
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname,col_names=FALSE, skip =1)

  #filters the data that includes the target mass
  df <- between(mc,limit,limit)

  #create new data based on contents
  allSpectra <- data.frame(df,f)

  #write new data to sep file
  write.table(allSpectra ,"allwobble.csv",
              append= T,
              sep=",",
              row = F
          )
}
```

The end result is a table with:

```
df f
FALSE filename
```

Also errors:

`Parsed with column specification: cols( X1 = col_character(), X2 = col_character() ) Warning: 2536 parsing failures.`

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a few things here to address:

First, with `read_tsv` you might want to specify the column types as `double` if appropriate, so values are not read in as character strings. This would affect your ability to filter and subset based on `Mass`.

Next, the `between` statement has the syntax of:

```
between(x, left, right)
```

where `x <= right` and `x >= left`. If you want to make sure your `mc` value is between 375.2 and 375.4 you might want `between(X1, mc-limit, mc+limit)` instead. Note that since no header was read in, the `Mass` variable is assumed first as `X1`.

When you use `write.table` and append, you might want to set `col.names` to `FALSE` (or include header on first write).

Hope this is helpful to you.

```
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname, col_names = FALSE, skip=1, col_types = "dd")

  #filters the data that includes the target mass
  df <- filter(df, between(X1, mc-limit, mc+limit))

  #create new data based on contents
  allSpectra <- data.frame(df,f)

  #write new data to sep file
  write.table(allSpectra ,"allwobble.csv",
              append= T,
              sep=",",
              row = F,
              col.names = FALSE
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ben. I had gotten to that point last night and had added a tolerance calculation. The "dd" definitely helped but required a col_names to get through another error. The final code is below. A parsing error comes up, but it does what it need to do!

```
tol<- .02 # the width of the search window
  mmneg <- mc - tol
  mmpos <- mc + tol

#finds the files with the correct extensions
fs <-list.files(path, pattern=glob2rx("*.txt$")) 
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname, skip =1,skip_empty_rows = T, col_types="dd", col_names=c("X1","X2"))

  #filters the data that excludes the offending peak
  df<- filter(df,between(X1,mmneg,mmpos))

  #create new data based on contents
  allSpectra <- data.frame(df,f)

  #write new data to sep file
  write.table(allSpectra ,"Caviunin_20_.csv",
              append= T,
              sep=",",
              row = F,
              col.names = F
  )
}
```